# What is the difference Between 'ACTION_CALL' and ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED'

Tags: android, call

as title, I do not know what is difference on 2 kinds of intent.

is anyone who knows these intent exactly ?

```
@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.ACTIVITY_INTENT_ACTION)

public static final String ACTION_CALL = "android.intent.action.CALL";

public static final String ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED = "android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED";
```